# How to add element to the top of an existing layout in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qlayout

I have an existing ColumnLayout and I want to add a new element on top of it without changing the existing ColumnLayout. I'm using an alias to reference the existing ColumnLayout but when I add the new element, it goes to the bottom of the layout. How can I add it to the top?

BaseColumn.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

Rectangle {
    property alias content: content
    anchors.fill: parent
    ColumnLayout {
        id: content
        Text {
            id: name
            text: qsTr("World")
        }
    }
}
```

Now in another file ChildColumn.qml I'm doing this but this adds this text at the bottom of the ColumnLayout and not the top.

```
BaseColumn {
    content.data [
        Text {
            id: name
            text: qsTr("Hello")
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I would probably put a place holder Item in BaseColumn that initially has 0 size, and insert your new content there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have two `ColumnLayout` so that user customizations will always go in front of yours, e.g.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    BaseColumn {
        Text {
            text: qsTr("Hello")
        }
    }
}

// BaseColumn.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
Frame {
    default property alias __content: topColumnLayout.data
    ColumnLayout {
        ColumnLayout {
            id: topColumnLayout
        }
        Text {
            id: name
            text: qsTr("World")
        }
    }
}
```

However, having said that, your requirement maybe simpler implemented with the `Page` `footer` property, e.g.

```
// BaseColumn.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
Page {
    default property alias __content: topColumnLayout.data
    ColumnLayout {
        id: topColumnLayout
    }
    footer: Text {
        id: name
        text: qsTr("World")
    }
}
```